# EXC_BAD_ACCESS: Core Data, NSFetchedResultsController and numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

In my UITableViewController class, I have this getter function for a NSFetchResultsController

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        FlipPadAppDelegate* app = (FlipPadAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:
            [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FundClass" inManagedObjectContext:[app managedObjectContext]]];
        NSSortDescriptor* sortdesp = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortdesp]];

        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                       managedObjectContext:[app managedObjectContext]
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                                                  cacheName:@"_Stock"];


        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;  
        [fetchRequest release];
        [sortdesp release];

        NSError *error;
        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
            // Handle error
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        }
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Somehow, when the app runs up to this point,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection %@", [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

}
```

it fires a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

There are two records in the sqllite database.

Why the exception? Is it because I have set `sectionNameKeyPath` to nil? Or because I did not set the dataSource of the view to this controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are logging an object @"numberOfRowsInSection %@" and the numberOfObjects is an int:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger numberOfObjects
```

Use @"numberOfRowsInSection %i" instead.

Comment: Thanks very much! It is exactly the problem! I have been looking into documentation for days, but I never thought it could be a NSLog/format string issue.